Curious about stuck BTC transaction
My transaction was sent before the halving, at only 22 sat /vbyte (per coinbase commerce's recommendation) and has been stuck for 7 days.
I'm not in a hurry, but I also want to make sure my funds are safe.
Would it be possible for me to initiate a cpfp to speed this up?  Someone told me I couldn't because the UTXOs were spent... I am not well versed in cpfp transactions so I wanted to double check.
Here is the transaction:
https://mempool.space/tx/aeddb0dce093e324c497d9827593a9fc81022051c26c58dd576d7c60b1fcb5cb
Bonus: Is there a default amount of time before it would be cleared from the mempool and returned to me?  Or does it just depend if fees got high enough to purge it?

P.S. I control the receiving wallet as well, could I do a cpfp using the receiving wallet?
